# Tickinterval of week,month,year in highcharts area spline chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to show the area spline chart chart based on week,month,year in highcharts. I tried the following tickinterval in xaxis categories but none should work. Please let me know if anyone knows.

The following codes tried.

```
 tickInterval: 24 * 3600000 * 7, // for week
 tickInterval: 24 * 3600000*30, // for month
 tickInterval: 24 * 3600000*365, // for year
```

This code not working and showing a single date only in xaxis categories.

Comment: Hi user2703151, if your problem has not been resolved, please provide me with the complete chart configuration object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *"tickInterval"* option in spline chart. You can use *"pointInterval"* and *"pointIntervalUnit"* options to set desired intervals. note that *"pointIntervalUnit"* can be set to **day**, **month** and **year**. if you wish to set your xAxis as weekly you can do that like this:

```
pointInterval: 7,
pointIntervalUnit: 'day'
```

You can find further guides in [this](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.pointInterval) link